# prisma config connect mongodb do not use admin user

Tags: mongodb, prisma, prisma-graphql

**How can I connect mongodb without adminUser?** Is there some methods help me to connect mongodb using `ai_app` user like below?

```
environment:
  PRISMA_CONFIG: |
    port: 4477
    # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
    # managementApiSecret: my-secret
    databases:
      default:
        connector: mongo
        uri: 'mongodb://ai_app:ai_app@192.168.1.157:27017/ai_app'
        migrations: false
```

Comment: Is it mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

Prisma will generate a database named `prisma` which not authorized to other mongodb user to execute read or write command except adminUser.

So if you want to connect mongodb with user A in prisma config file. You should grant readWrite role to A.

```
use ai_app
db.grantRolesToUser("ai_app", [{role: "readWrite", db: "prisma"}])
```